# In wix repairing a setup throws an error

Tags: windows, installation, wix

To repair an uninstall condition:

```
<Condition Message="True">(LAUNCHFROMEXE = "True")</Condition>
```

This condition throws an  install error. But  use below  condition:

```
<Condition Message="True">LAUNCHFROMEXE</Condition>
```

I am able to repair the setup.

Answer (score 0):

The first example requires the `LAUNCHFROMEXE` property to be set to the string value `"True"`. The second condition simply requires `LAUNCHFROMEXE` to be set to any value at all (i.e. the value needs to be non-blank). So in the second case, something in your repair operations is setting `LAUNCHFROMEXE` to some value (maybe it is initialized to `"False"`) and thus is working.

In this [old blog entry of mine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2006/08/22/712812.aspx), I mention why you should always consider adding `Installed OR` to your launch conditions. I would recommend doing the same above.